# How to get earliest date from time parameter without including data that have data older than time parameter in SQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm struggling for some time with kind of painfull problem.

What I want to achieve is to find the blue circle on the image below. It is to find `date` where some `name` occurs first in the database but it is the furthest date out of all possible occurences (furthest in terms of distance between `start date parameter` and all possible gaps between start date and data)

I know how to find the date right after start date. To do this I'm using that query.

```
SELECT *
FROM animals
WHERE date(date) > '2020-01-01'
ORDER BY date ASC
LIMIT 1 ;
```

But I don't know how to exclude the data that occurs before `2020-01-01` in this query.

I would like to do it in form of SQL query.

[image: help image]

My SQL table looks like this:

| date | name | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-02-01 | dog | 45.5 |
| 2022-02-01 | cat | 2.5 |
| 2022-02-01 | snake | 2.5 |
| 2022-01-31 | dog | 42.5 |
| 2022-01-31 | cat | 3.4 |
| 2022-01-31 | snake | 43.2 |
| 2022-01-30 | dog | 43.2 |
| 2022-01-30 | cat | 43.2 |
| 2022-01-30 | snake | 43.2 |
| 2022-01-29 | dog | 43.2 |
| 2022-01-29 | snake | 43.2 |
| 2022-01-28 | dog | 43.2 |

And let's say that I'm looking for date after `2022-01-28`.
Now gap between `start_date` and first occurence of dog is 0 because dog has data for `2022-01-28`. For snake it is 1 day (`2022-01-29`) and for cat it's 2 (`2022-01-30`)

So my result should be 2022-01-30 (2 days from start_date for cat) because it is the furthest from the `start_date`

Comment: Could you provide some sample data and expect result?

Comment: Yes, I updated the post, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Search for `distinct on` and you'll see several explanations on how to solve this.

This should work (I changed date field to event_date to keep it less confusing)

```
with earliest_dates as (
 select distinct on (name) name, event_date 
 from animals
 where event_date > '2020-01-01'
 order by name, event_date
)
select  max(event_date) - min(event_date) as days
from earliest_dates;
```

sql fiddle link for test setup http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/67389/4/0